# javascript forEach inside forEach , elements of same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, game-development

im trying to make a game and i need to know which platform of the array is above another platform

and i need to use a forEach inside other foreach using the same array i need to compare them all with echaoter

```
platforms.forEach(platform =>{
    platforms.forEach(other_platform =>{
        if(platform.y - 1 <= other_platform.y + other_platform.height)
            platform.isSurface = false
    })
})
```

i did try doing the code example and its not working

Comment: If you want to manipulate an array it is better to use map instead of forEach. you need to return the inside loop as well es the isSurface line, and save the whole thing in a new variable. Other than that, if you prefer to stick with forEach, you get the original array as third argument (second being the index). You can use this to manipulate the data, but it is better to use map, because map creates a copy for you.

Comment: escuze me , @Stiegi , im new to js , how could i code this with foreach , please give me an example !

Comment: Can you please provide a sample object/array structure?
How does `platforms` array look like? 
 @IndieValentin

Comment: well , i'm just pushing them trough a function , that's it i just need to know how to do this , u can put toghether a sample with fruits if u want , the platform is class in my project which has position{ x,y} and width and height

Comment: The Multiply each element example on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp is what I mean. There you can see how you manipulate the original array